# PHP PDO error while adding to the base

Tags: php, pdo

I send variable in function where should work PHP PDO commands, the variable actually exists(I check it) but after, in PDO, I get error.

Here is the function:

```
public static function addMenu( $name ){
    $db = ConnectDB();

    var_dump($name); echo '<br />';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . self::getTableName() . " name VALUES :nameMenu";
    $stmt = $db->prepare ( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam(':nameMenu', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

And here that error which I get:

> string(4) "rher"
>   
>  **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException'
>   with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'name VALUES 'rher'' at line 1' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sea\public_html\admin\backend\DB\tables\TypePlacesTable.php:30
>   Stack trace:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sea\public_html\admin\backend\DB\tables\TypePlacesTable.php(30):
>   PDOStatement->execute()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sea\public_html\admin\backend\index.php(18):
>   TypePlacesTable::addMenu('rher') {main}   thrown in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\sea\public_html\admin\backend\DB\tables\TypePlacesTable.php**
>   on line **30**

Comment: Not sure if its required but try putting `()` around column names and `()` around the named params might be needed. e.g. `$sql = "INSERT INTO " . self::getTableName() . " (\`name\`) VALUES (:nameMenu)";` Never tried it without () before

Comment: also whenever debugging errors that are to do with sql you should `echo $sql` and paste it directly into the database to see if there are any issues there. For future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh,now working, I just forget add "(" and ")" for variables, need been so

```
public static function addMenu( $name ){
        $db = ConnectDB();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . self::getTableName() . " (name) VALUES (:nameMenu)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare ( $sql );
        $stmt->bindParam(':nameMenu', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```